# Button background color is not showing on edge, but working on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I am designing my login page. I have added button background color, which is showing on chrome and firefox perfectly, but it does not showing on microsoft edge. Below are my HTML and CSS,
note - I have tried with many color, all are working on chrome and firefox but not in edge

HTML

```css
         .index-un-right-nav-buttom{
                float: left;
                height: auto;
                padding-top: 10px;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                width: 100%;
            }
                .index-un-right-nav-submit-button{
                    float: left;
                    padding-top: 5px;
                    padding-bottom: 5px;
                    height: 50px;
                    width: 100px;
                    margin-top: 20px;
                    margin-bottom: 20px;
                    margin-left: 10%;
                    border: none;
                    outline: none;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    background-color: #007182fb;
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 18px;
                    border-radius: 50px;
                }
```

```html
<span class="index-un-right-nav-button">
    <button class="index-un-right-nav-submit-button">Login</button>
</span>
```

In firefox,
[image: image in firefox]

In Edge
[image: in edge]

In chrome,
[image: in chrome]

Comment: You must set Hex color with 6 digits so try without `fb`:https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/color/hex-to-rgb.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edge doesn't support the 8-digit color notation. See [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-rrggbbaa).

Use

```css
background-color: rgba(0, 113, 130, 0.984);
```

instead.

Comment: It worked in rgba(), is there any particular reason that it does not support an 8 digit? Asking it because I have added 8 digit in few other buttons as well.

Comment: No idea. Perhaps they didn't see the need to implement it, because there was already the rgba notation. Or they just haven't got around to it, but they will soon, and then the matter will be moot in a year or so.

Comment: The latest version of MS/Edge still doesn't support this.

Comment: @SoichiHayashi CanIUse says it does since v79, and it does indeed work here in v81.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing

```
background-color: #007182fb;
```

to

```
background-color: #007182;
```

hope that fixes the problem.

Also clearing the browser cashe might help.

Comment: this takes off transparency/opacity of the color which is last 2 chars in the 8 digit (first) example... so basically this isnt the same color... the right answer is to convert it from hex to rgb color as the right answer shows...

Answer (score 0):

Edge (and IE11) doesn't support opacity values inside the background-color value
use

```
background-color: rgba(0, 113, 130, 0.95);
```